# Force rediction for mod-rewrite

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to force a redirect when someone access on a page where there's a `RewriteRule`.
For example, if I go to

```
index.php?category&cat_id=1
```

I want to force a rediction to

```
category-1.html
```

**Here's my code :**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^category-([0-9]+).html index.php?category&cat_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^article-([0-9]+).html index.php?read&art_id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^register index.php?register [L]
RewriteRule ^index index.php [L]
```

Thanks in advance for your help
**Cheers, MrZ**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a new redirect rule at top:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} /index\.php\?(category)&cat_id=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1-%2.html? [R=302,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^category-([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?category&cat_id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^article-([0-9]+)\.html$ index.php?read&art_id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^register/?$ index.php?register [L]

RewriteRule ^index/?$ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, but, is there any solution for auto-detect if the rewrited page where we want to be redicted are in a specific folder or not ? (whitout manual edit of rewritebase /)

Comment: Sorry I didn't understand your question in comments, can you clarify?

Comment: Oh sorry i finally understand, sorry for the too late reply